# Calling recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I try to write a recursion function which gives me the possibility to work with (add some text) between only "li" html tag. Here are all cases which I can have:

```
Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 Test 2 
<ul>
  <li>Coffee dfg dfg dfg </li>
  <li>Tea dfg df gdf gfdg </li>
  <li>Mifdg dfg fdg lkdf gdf gdf </li>
</ul> 

Test 3 Test 3 Test 3 Test 3 Test 3 Test 3
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>

  </li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

Test 4 Test 4 Test 4 Test 4 Test 4 Test 4 
<ul>
  <li>Coffee dfg dfg dfg </li>
  <li>
        <ol>
            <li>Coffee</li>
            <li>Tea</li>
            <li>Milk</li>
        </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Mifdg dfg fdg lkdf gdf gdf </li>
</ul>
```

My code:

```
public static String isInnerTag(String text){

    final StringBuilder olBuilder = new StringBuilder(text);

    int beginText = text.indexOf("<ol>");
    int endText = olBuilder.indexOf("</ol>");

    String innerText = text.substring(beginText + 4, endText);

    innerText = innerText.replaceAll("</li>", "");
    String [] li = innerText.split("<li>");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < li.length; i++) {

        String temp = i + " " + li[i].toString();
        sb.append(temp);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
    return text;
}
```

output:

1 Coffee
2 Tea
3 Milk
4 Milk
5 Milk
6 Milk
7 Milk last

I want to add before text in li tag eg. 1, 2, 3 and so on, AND for inner (test 4) for the first li 1, the next li (in next ol) 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and so on.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where is the attempted recursive code that you've come up with?

Comment: Best of luck! I will pray for your success.

Comment: Also, why use recursion at all? Just walk your document (using xpath or similar), selecting all `<li>` elements. No need to complicate things.

Comment: Just do it! Create a nestable data structure and iterate over it rendering the tags in the process.

Comment: I only find html tags here where is the java code

Comment: Unfortunatelly, also I wait for maybe some hints, how to solve it in the best way, I suppose that I need recursion but it in not a requirement of course.

Comment: yes i want to code it in java

Comment: Can I use from xpath with such a problem ? XPath is not only for xml files ?