# How apply foreach loop for every line of string

Tags: java, loops, foreach, iteration

I have a string:

```
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk last</li>
```

and I want to interate over all li-tags (in order to add some text between the tags):

```
    for (char c: innerText.toCharArray()) {

        if(c == '<'){
            // process the text but in this way 
           //I iterate over whole text as a one line
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the contents or the tags too?

Comment: Is this HTML ? Can the processing be done on the client?

Comment: Yes, it is simple html, it is a standalone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with the following code:

```
String text = "<li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk last</li>";
    text = text.replaceAll("</li>", "");
    String[] results = text.split("<li>");
    // The first one is empty, remove it
    for (int i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(results[i]);
    }
```

Output in Console is as follows:

```
Coffee
Tea
Milk
Milk
Milk
Milk
Milk last
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a parser, you can use regular expressions for this as follows:

```
String regex = "<li>((?:\\w|\\s)+)</li>";
String list = "..."; //your list

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(list);

while (m.find()) 
{
    String ofInterest = m.group(1);
    //doSomething
}
```

`((?:\\w|\\s)+)` is a capturing group that takes characters from `[A-Za-z_0-9]` or any whitespace, where the `+` indicates that there must be at least one character.  Use a `*` instead if there could be no characters in between.
`m.group(1)` simply extracts what is between `<li>` and `</li>`, where the `1` cooresponds to the first capturing group.

You can replace what's inside the capturing group with whatever you consider to be valid. 
Here's a tutorial on [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks guys, stackoverflow is great ! ! !

Comment: @MrPhi Glad I could help.  If you don't know regular expressions already, I highly suggest you go through the tutorial.  They are really helpful with a lot of tasks.  Good luck!

Comment: Exactly, i have a problems with text processing, I do not know when use DOM, when SAX, when RegEX, There are lots of possibilities and it is easy to get lost in all of them. The question is only part of greater problem to solve, for now thanks to the Q&A I get a way in which should I will go. Thanks one more time all of you!

Comment: Could you give me a hint whether your solution is the best for my main problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903402/calling-recursion?noredirect=1#comment29612056_19903402 ?

Comment: @MrPhi I'm about to pass out, not sure if it's because I'm extremely tired or not, but I'm not entirely sure what your other question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for parsing HTML text or [DOM parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) to parser the XML string. Then you can pass the parsed value to the for-each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String str ="<li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk</li><li>Milk last</li>";
    String[] temp =str.replaceAll("</li>", "").split("<li>");
    String result ="";
    for (String value: temp){
        result = result + "<li>";
        // update the value here if needed
        result = result + value;        
        result = result+ "<li>";
    }


     System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    String str
            = "<li>Coffee</li>"
            + "<li>Tea</li>"
            + "<li>Milk</li>"
            + "<li>Milk</li>"
            + "<li>Milk</li>"
            + "<li>Milk</li>"
            + "<li>Milk last</li>";
   String[] products= str.substring(4, str.length()-5).split("</li><li>");
    for (String prod : products) {
        System.out.println(prod);  
    }
```

### Output:

```
Coffee
Tea
Milk
Milk
Milk
Milk
Milk last
```

Answer (score 1):

it shows that you are parsing some html elements,
jsoup is one the great java html parsers,

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Yes, you are right but I do not want to use from some frameworks, I want to seize the Java to the maximum ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As the OP is wanting to `add some text between the tags` I suggest that he use jquery instead of a server side solution.

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  str = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(str + " Other text");
 });
```

Comment: What is OP ? Thanks but it is standalone app.

Comment: OP = Short for Original Poster. Used on online message boards and forums.

Answer (score 0):

It can all be done on one line:

```
for (String option : innerText.replaceAll("^.*?<li>|</li>.*?$", "").split("</li>\\s*<li>")) {
   System.out.println(option);
}
```